# What is the code in VBA in Excel which will select the first cell where the macro has initially started?

Tags: excel, vba

What is the VBA code in Excel for selecting the cell where your macro has initially started. For instance, I will run the macro n times in one workbook and each time before starting it I will choose different cell - A2, A3, A4 etc. What I need is that the very last line of the macro must be to select the cell where the macro has initially started - A2, A3, A4 etc.

My code now looks like this:

```
Selection.Copy
Range("I2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

So, the first line is copy - I started the macro from cell A2 and copied the content and pasted in cell I2. Then I want to select again cell A2 because I will copy all cells 3 columns rightward from cell A2 (B2, C2 and D2 must then be copied). On the next run, I will start the macro from cell A3 and then I want to copy all cells 3 columns rightward from cell A3 and so on.

I hope I explained my issue as clear as possible. Could you please help me with that problem?

Comment: Selecting a cell to copy its value is a bad habit, anyhow. No need of any selection.

Comment: After the initial copy where will you paste to? When will the code end?

Comment: Your question has nothing at all to do with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). I am deleting that tag. Please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don not need to select anything, but if you insist you can firstly set the cell to be used as the active cell:

```
Sub copyFromReferenceCell()
   Dim cellCopy As Range
     Set cellCopy = ActiveCell 'if you want using a previously selected cell
     cellCopy.Copy Destination:=cellCopy.Offset(0, 8)
     Range(cellCopy.Offset(0, 1), cellCopy.Offset(0, 3)).Copy Destination:=cellCopy.Offset(0, 9)
End Sub
```

You did not tell us where do you need copying the range of three cells, I only supposed that you try copying in a similar way and choose "J2". If my supposition is wrong, you can set a different range

Comment: thanks, but on the next run I want to copy cell A3. So i will select cell A3 and then run the macro.

Comment: @MilanovI  I adapted the code to use the first selected cell and then copying using Offset. Did I correctly deduce what you need? I mean, it will firstly copy in "I2" and then in "J2:L2", and then according to selected cell row.

Comment: Thank you, now I see the logic. I'm new to VBA so I didn't know how to structure the code.

Comment: @MilanovI  But, does the code what you need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951209/how-can-i-design-the-code-in-vba-in-order-to-refer-to-a-previously-already-newly 
Yes, but here I added up some more to it. Would be glad if you can help me there too. Thanks.

Comment: @MilanovI I tried answering your second question. But it is good to know that we  here, when somebody answer our question, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar, will know that the code works as you asked for... And, it will also be necessary to previously make some research on internet and come here with a piece of code, even if it does not work as you need. We here try helping people solving their **onw** code if it does not do what they need...