# How can I design the code in VBA in order to refer to a previously already newly created workbook in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I refer in VBA to a previously newly created workbook within the same macro? For example, I copy something from A2 in the active workbook, then I create a new workbook, paste there in cell B3, return to the first workbook, copy cell A3, return again to the newly created workbook and paste in in cell B4.

So, what I need is the code for this part of the sentence: "return again to the newly created workbook"

My code till now is this:

```
        `Selection.Copy`
        `Workbooks.Add`
        `Range("B3").Paste`
        `Windows("First_WorkBook.xlsm").Activate`
        `Range("A3").Select`
        `Selection.Copy`
```

The last two lines are missing: returning to the new workbook and pasting there.

Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: You have used the word rightward twice which would mean to the right. So if you want to copy `A5` and the three cells to its right, it would mean copying `A5:D5`. If you would then paste to the cells `C10:C13` you would be transposing i.e. in this particular case, you would be copying a row range to a column range. Please do clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. You should also declare the sheets where the ranges will be copied:

```
Sub testNewWBCopy()
  Dim actWb As Workbook, newWb As Workbook, shAct As Worksheet, shNew As Worksheet
  Set actWb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set shAct = actWb.Sheets(1)
  
  Set newWb = Workbooks.Add
  Set shNew = newWb.Sheets(1)
  
  shAct.Range("A2").Copy Destination:=shNew.Range("B3")
  shAct.Range("A3").Copy Destination:=shNew.Range("B4")
End Sub
```

And it is good to avoid selecting, activating, if possible... They only consume Excel resources and make the code slower.

Comment: Thanks, may I ask why we don't use the variables actWb and shAct? Furthermore, it gives me an error for unknown reason. The error is: Run-time error "1004": Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed. Also, I noticed that it creates two new workbooks. Maybe because before I put your code I also had another one: Workbooks.Add.

Comment: @MilanovI Did you try the code exactly as it is? If not, what did you try modifying? If yes, did you observe that it works **on the first sheet of the active workbook**? Then, why do you say that the the `shAct` is not used? And `actWb` has been used only to be able to fully qualify the sheet from where the code copies data. The code, as it is, cannot raise such an error. On which code line such an error does appear?

Comment: sorry, excuse me I didn't specify. Instead the cells addresses I am trying to connect also with the answer you gave me in the other question I asked.
So, my code now looks like this: 
`Dim cellscopy As Range`
 `Dim actWb As Workbook, newWb As Workbook, shAct As Worksheet, shNew As Worksheet`
 `Set cellscopy = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3))`
 `Set actWb = ActiveWorkbook`
 `Set shAct = actWb.Sheets(1)`
  
 `Set newWb = Workbooks.Add`
 `Set shNew = newWb.Sheets(1)`
  
 `shAct.Range(cellscopy).Copy Destination:=shNew.Range("A4")`
The error 1004 is in the last line

Comment: @MilanovI You tried, but you did it wrongly. `ActiveCell` is referring the active cell. You should fully qualify it. When somebody post an answer, **you should test it as it is** and only after that to comment about errors. If you try using it in your way, this does not mean that **the posted code** "gives you an error...

Comment: The code works yes. I gave it a green tick, but I had an additional question upon it why my variation doesn't work. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you. And I select a certain cell with values and its adjacent cells also have values because I want when I start the macro the range starts from active cell to 2 adjacent cells to it.

Comment: @MilanovI Not sure I understand what you mean... If you need some specific code, please edit your question and explain what you need. And then paste the code you use, based on mine. I cannot understand it form your comment. I will try helping you, even if we here open new questions for new thinks not mentioned in the initial one... And, no need to tick anything, if the answer does not satisfy you. I do not hunt more notoriety. I only try helping.

Comment: I updated (edited) the above question which I posted. I hope I could explain good my issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @MilanovI I am afraid you did not understand anything from both pieces of code I supplied... You did not understand the community spirit, too. I was trying to tell you that you firstly must learn asking a question and **test the answer TO YOUR QUESTION**. When you try using the code **in your way** nobody will understand what's happening with the code returning an error. Now, the problem (for me) is that **you completely changed your initial question**, which did not mention anything about filtering and I still cannot understand what you want. Asking in this way, nobody will be able to help...

Answer (score 0):

### Copy from One Worksheet to Another (in a Different Workbook)

- Using variables will do the trick.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCells()
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("First_Workbook.xlsm")
    
    ' To avoid an error occuring if the workbook is not open, you could
    ' replace the previous line with the following code block:
'    On Error Resume Next
'    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("First_Workbook.xlsm")
'    On Error GoTo 0
'    If swb Is Nothing Then
'        MsgBox "The workbook is not open.", vbCritical, "CopyCells"
'        Exit Sub
'    End If
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Copy
    
    sws.Range("A2").Copy
    dws.Range("B2").PasteSpecial
    sws.Range("A3").Copy
    dws.Range("B3").PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' In this particular case you would rather do:
'    sws.Range("A2:A3").Copy
'    dws.Range("B2:B3").PasteSpecial
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ' Or:
    'sws.Range("A2:A3").Copy dws.Range("B2:B3")
    ' Or (for copying values only):
    'dws.Range("B2:B3").Value = sws.Range("A2:A3").Value
    
End Sub
```